# Laravel Eloquent Collection show object is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I upgraded recently to 5.4 and I'm changing from passing an id and loading up the record, to passing the order object directly to the show function. I'm using this method on a couple of newly installed projects so I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the upgrade. Also, I tried the same thing on my InvoicesController with the same result.

My route for orders:

```
Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');
```

And here's an excerpt from the OrderController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Order;
use App\User;
use App\Item;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\OrderRequest;

class OrderController extends Controller {

    public function show(Order $order)
    {
        dd($order);
    }
}
```

The dd returns this though - with no data:

```
Invoice {#738 ▼
  #table: "invoices"
  +timestamps: true
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

Comment: What your `url` looks like, is that plural (orders) ?

Comment: It's singular.. the index is /order and to view an order order/250 for example.

Comment: Are you sure this dump is from this controller action? The dumped object is from `Inoice` class... ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess in show method the parameter should be the object of OrderRequest. not the object of Order.

```
public function show(OrderRequest $order){
    dd($order);
}
```

Comment: When I make that change it just redirects me to the index

Answer (score 0):

make sure your html like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('order.show',$your_order_id) }}">show</a>
```

Controller:

```
 public function show(Order $order)
    {
        dd($order);
    }
```

or

```
  public function show(\App\Order $order)
        {
            dd($order);
        }
```

Hope it helps